# Do all LDAP servers have anonymous access?

Tags: ldap, authentication

I need to configure programmatic ldap authentication in an application. But I'd rather not hardcode passwords anywhere. So it would be very convenient if ldap servers all have anonymous access for authentication purposes.

Being a bit new to ldap, this might look like a silly question.

Comment: Hardcoding credentials is indeed a stupid idea. But relying on LDAP always having anon read access is just as naive. Why don't you either let the user enter a password, or have your app (or the service that gets the info) run under a certain user that has read access?

Comment: Because it is a Java web application. It needs to regularly connect with the LDAP to authenticate/authorize users. So I need some safe way to leave a password somewhere.

Answer (score 4):

No you can't rely on anonymous access always being available and your application should also support authentication with what is typically called a *"Bind DN"*.

Yes, often that requires storing a cleartext password in the configuration of  your application which is not ideal, but it is still fairly common to do so and in many cases preferable to anonymous access to the LDAP directory.

In addition you should allow your application to be configured to use SSL or not, the ability to submit a client certificate (some LDAP servers allow certificate-based authentication instead of that ugly password), set a BaseDN and configure either a custom filter or an alternative username attribute (as quite often the usernames people use is not the DN).

Just to name some other considerations as well.

Comment: Your feedback is much appreciated ! At least now I know the anonymous access is an option - but also it shouldn't be the only one. I don't know about the 'bind dn' but I'll look into it.

Answer (score -1):

Yes , LDAP supports anonymous read access , but it depends on how it is configured to support this feature. You may configure ldap to have such access on local LAN. If you are not sure , just ask your system administrator. I am using this feature in a Java application , to lookup users in LDAP for authentication.